# System.ArgumentException: An HttpContext is required to perform this operation. Check that this operation is being performed during a web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting Exception like in the topic:

> **System.ArgumentException**: An HttpContext is required to perform this
>   operation. Check that this operation is being performed during a web
>   request.

Everytime I'm trying to test one method.
I created a HttpContext:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    #region declarations
    Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    Mock<IAntiForgeryValidator> antiForgeryMock = new Mock<IAntiForgeryValidator>();
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    #endregion

    #region repository mock setups
    mock.Setup(m => m.deviceRepository.Get(
        It.IsAny<List<Expression<Func<Device, bool>>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Device>, IOrderedQueryable<Device>>>(),
        null))
        .Returns(new[] { new Device { Id = 1, Manufacturer = "a", Name = "b", CatalogNo = "x" } });
    mock.Setup(m => m.deviceRepository.Get()).Returns(new[] { new Device { Id = 1, Manufacturer = "a", Name = "b", CatalogNo = "z" } });
    mock.Setup(m => m.deviceRepository.GetByID(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Device { Id = 1, Manufacturer = "a", Name = "b", CatalogNo = "15" });
    mock.Setup(m => m.deviceRepository.GetByID(It.IsInRange(-1, 1, Range.Exclusive))).Returns(default(Device));
    #endregion

    #region Mocking Request in purpose of testing Post Methods 
    Mock<HttpRequestBase> Request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    WebHeaderCollection Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
    Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    Headers.Add("Content-Length", "82");
    Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
    Request.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(Headers);
    context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(Request.Object);
    #endregion

    #region Mocking Validation 
     antiForgeryMock.Setup(m => m.Validate(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback((string cookieToken, string formToken) =>
        {
            // call back
        });
    #endregion

    DC = new DeviceController(fakeRepo);
    DC.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object,new RouteData(),DC);
}
```

But when trying to execute code below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditPost()
{
    var data = default(Device);
    var result = DC.Edit(data);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting an exception telling me that there is no `HttpContext`. I created it and bound it to controller object.

Below code I'm testing:

```
 [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,Name,Manufacturer,CatalogNo")] Device device)
    {
        ValidateRequestHeader(Request);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(device.Name) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(device.Manufacturer) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(device.CatalogNo))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Niepoprawne dane");
            return PartialView(device);
        }
        unitOfWork.deviceRepository.Update(device);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Index") });
    }
AntiForgeryValidator a = new AntiForgeryValidator();

public void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request) 
{
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";

    if (request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
    {
        string[] tokens = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"].Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    a.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    //AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
public interface IAntiForgeryValidator
{
    //void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request);
    void Validate(string cookieToken, string formToken);
}
public class AntiForgeryValidator : IAntiForgeryValidator
{
    public void Validate(string cookieToken, string formToken)
    {
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

@Update
StackTrace is pointing on this method to cause exception: `AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);`

Comment: Can you show where you are creating your mock context? In a test setup method?

Comment: I Updated question with full Initialization

Comment: As always, when you are troubleshooting a problem involving an unexpected exception, you should look at the stack trace of the exception to pinpoint what method is throwing the exception.

Comment: Stack trace points at the method `AntiForgery.Validate(CookieToken,FormToken)` But this isn't helping me in anything

Comment: That does help a whole bunch, you set up your mock `AntiForgeryValidator`, but then never associate that with your context.

Comment: Can you show me how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like you mock your `unitOfWork` variable in `Edit()`, set up your `IAntiForgeryValidator`. Right now you are explicitly creating a "real" `AntiForgeryValidator` using that constructor call outside of `Edit()`. Simply switch `a` to be a variable the same as `unitOfWork` (I am assuming you are injecting `unitOfWork` somehow), and have `a` be an `IAntiForgeryValidator`, and not an explicity `AntiForgeryValidator`, and then it should work. I am assuming that your mock calls to `unitOfWork` are working fine and I can't provide more detail without you showing how your `unitOfWork` variable is declared/instantiated in your controller.

Comment: Yes.I'm injecting dependecies into controllers. I'll try do it as you suggested. And yes mock calls of unitOfwork are working like a charm. OK. Now I'm gettin null pointer exception. So I'm going somewhere